# Changing the typeset hotkey in texshop

Tags: texshop

I was wondering whether there is a way to change the typeset hotkey in texshop for mac from `CMD + T` to something such as `CMD + D`. I have been looking for it but found no results, does anyone know of such a way?

Comment: I believe that this needs to be done in Mac System Preferences: `Keyboard/Shortcuts`.  Select `App Shortcuts` and then `+` to add. Select the TeXShop as the Application in the pop-up window, the Menu Title: `Typeset` (exactly as the TeXShop menu item) and select the Keyboard Shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

The procedure is

1. go to System Preferences
2. Keyboard
3. Keyboard Shortcuts
4. Application Shortcuts
5. Click `+'
6. Application = Tex –> TexShop
7. I added command + R as Keyboard Shortcut for Menu Title = Typeset
8. now just press command+R in TexShop to compile the full doc.

If you want to include bib, change it to Bibliography instead of Typeset.
Restart TeXshop for any changes in the shortcut. :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Answers that are link-only are discouraged because links die. This one is also basically what is said in the comment. Could you edit your answer to explain the actual solution isinstead of just giving the link. This would be more helpful to others.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the other comment! (New to the forum) I'll just delete my comment later because you're right it's just repeated.

Comment: Actually it's good to have an answer, so rather than delete yours (comments aren't really answers) you can just fill in the details in yours.

Comment: Thanks, just did it.

Comment: +1 thanks for this.